# Azure Pre-compiled Function failed with unexpected error: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0...'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have the following NuGet dependencies in my project (Azure Pre-compiled Function):

```
<package id="Common.Logging" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net461"/>
<package id="Common.Logging.Core" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net461"/>
```

When the function code is executed (using the VS tooling), I receive the following error :

> Loader failed with unexpected error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

The `Common.Logging.dll` file exists inside the `bin` folder.
What can be the root cause ?

Thanks for your help!
Regards

Comment: Can someone confirm this issue is linked to https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992 ?

Comment: Is something missing in your text after "this NuGet packages :"?

Comment: Yes, now fixed! Thanks